# When I add new .feature file in intellij in resources folder ,it is not getting added ,I tried refresh as well

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber-jvm

I'm adding new feature file to the resources/appfeatures folder ,it is accepting addition of new .feature file but after adding there is no feature file even I tried refreshing as well in Intellij

Answer (score 0):

When I refreshed the new .feature file added is not appeared but when I close the folder and open it again instead of refresh it is appeared